# npm package.json scripts not being called

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I have the following scripts section in my projects package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "seed": "node bin/seed",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

If i run `$ npm test` I get this:

```
>npm test

> node-mongo-seeds@0.0.1 test C:\Users\m089269\WebstormProjects\node-mongo-seeds
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

"Error: no test specified"
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

If i run `$ npm seed`, I get this:

```
npm seed

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\m089269\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@1.4.3 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Why does it recognize my `test` script but not my `seed` script?

**EDIT**

When I try `npm run-script seed` I get this error which is expected because I don't pass in a `-d` param:

```
$ npm run-script seed

> node-mongo-seeds@0.0.1 seed C:\Users\m089269\WebstormProjects\node-mongo-seeds
> node bin/seed

Populate mongo from a set of .json files.
 Usage: $ node seed

Options:
  -d  The path to your mongo db  [required]

Missing required arguments: d

npm ERR! node-mongo-seeds@0.0.1 seed: `node bin/seed`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
...
```

When I try `npm run-script seed -d "localhost/ease"` I get this error.

```
npm run-script seed -d localhost/ease-dev
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.4.3
npm info using node@v0.10.26
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\m089269\WebstormProjects\node-mongo-seeds\node_modules\seed\package.json'
...
```

Why is it looking for a package.json in node_modules\seed? Seed is not even a dependency.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts):

> npm supports the "scripts" member of the package.json script, for the following scripts:
>
> - prepublish: Run BEFORE the package is published. (Also run on local `npm install` without any arguments.)
> - prepare: Run both BEFORE the package is packed and published, on local `npm install` without any arguments, and when installing git dependencies (See below). This is run AFTER `prepublish`, but BEFORE `prepublishOnly`.
> - prepublishOnly: Run BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on `npm publish`.
> - prepack: run BEFORE a tarball is packed (on `npm pack`, `npm publish`, and when installing git dependencies).
> - postpack: Run AFTER the tarball has been generated and moved to its final destination.
> - publish, postpublish: Run AFTER the package is published.
> - preinstall: Run BEFORE the package is installed
> - install, postinstall: Run AFTER the package is installed.
> - preuninstall, uninstall: Run BEFORE the package is uninstalled.
> - postuninstall: Run AFTER the package is uninstalled.
> - preupdate: Run BEFORE the package is updated with the update command.
> - update, postupdate: Run AFTER the package is updated with the update command.
> - pretest, test, posttest: Run by the `npm test` command.
> - prestop, stop, poststop: Run by the `npm stop` command.
> - prestart, start, poststart: Run by the `npm start` command.
> - prerestart, restart, postrestart: Run by the `npm restart` command. Note: `npm restart` will run the stop and start scripts if no `restart` script is provided.
>
> Additionally, arbitrary scripts can be run by doing `npm run-script <stage> <pkg>`.

You can see the reason why your `npm test` script works is because `npm test` is a built-in command.  You must use `npm run-script` if you want to execute a script that is not executed by a built-in npm command.

Comment: That's very helpful info. Please see my edit to my question though as something is still not right.

Comment: It seems that npm run-script does not currently support passing in arguments. So for now I've just hard coded the -d value into the scripts section `"scripts": {"seed": "node bin/seed -d localhost/ease"...`

Comment: Assuming npm passes the local environment to scripts, you could have the node script read in environment variables for setting parameters.

Comment: Note an alias of `npm run-script` is `npm run`

Comment: Note that they have made some changes in the latest version. Notably, they removed the update/shrinkwrap script and added a version script

Answer (score 23):

Custom scripts declared in the package.json can be ran with the `npm run <your-script>` form in your shell.

Try `npm run seed` or `npm run test`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

To execute the custom scripts in package.json using below

**npm run-script seed**

or

**npm run-script** *< custom script >*

or you can use

**npm run** *< custom script >*

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem in your seed.js, if it has an error, when you try to run
**npm run seed**
the error will be: it can not find the seed, which will mistaken you that there is a problem with your package.json,

In my case, the used bcrypt in the seed file was not recognizable by the system, so I had to reinstall the bcrypt, after that the issue with not finding the "seed" script was solved automatically.
Try attaching a debugger to find the root problem in your seed.js.