# Google App Engine with separate processor script

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, redis, pm2, forever

I am using GAE to set up a simple REST API which allows me to process data in MongoDB.

Additionally, I have a forever script (like a daemon process) which is running a redis based queue.

I need to run my queue separately from my server instance... I am confused as to how to set this up in google app engine. Should I create a second project with a new server instance?

My package.json has this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

I suppose I will need either a new project or a second app engine instance. Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could just make it another [service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) inside your existing application. Long running tasks are possible, but they're not really a good fit for GAE. Maybe you could break it up in a (possibly endless) sequence of smaller tasks, GAE is quite good at these.

Comment: I am trying to use google cloud tasks for my solution with an "execute in seconds" option

Comment: I didn't play with those yet, I just used regular GAE push tasks.

Comment: Yeah they're in beta.. still doesn't work that well as there isnt much documentation and it didnt work for me. Do push tasks have any limits? Can I set up infinite push tasks? cloud tasks seemed to be a good choice for me because they let you "delay" your job in seconds... Would my app get out of control if i did a sleep or setTimeout  in a regular push task?

Comment: You don't need to sleep in tasks - that'd be a waste. You can just schedule them "later", using a relative delay/countdown or an absolute ETA when you enqueue them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475174/do-google-app-engine-pull-queues-return-tasks-in-fifo-order/40478036#40478036. There are some quotas, but pretty generous, my app didn't even make a dent in them.

Comment: Oh that's great. I am using node.js do you know a tutorial to get started?

Comment: Oh my push notifications are generated by the user and randomly sent out by the server. I will have to create them programatically. Cron jobs wont be the best for this

Comment: Apologies, I forgot that node.js doesn't have support for task queues... :(

Answer (score 0):

To decompose functionality of your app it is possible to [deploy separate services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) in one project, that will serve different tasks, and communicate one to each other. 
Thank to micro services you get benefits on various levels:

1. Code isolation
2. Data isolation
3. Performance overhead
4. Cost accounting
5. Permissions and security
6. Request tracing

Please check [documentation to know more how Contracts, Addressing, and APIs for Microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/designing-microservice-api) works.

To communicate between App Engine services and products in the Google Cloud, [you can use Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-pub-sub). Thank to this you can trigger background processing, and deal with life cycle events.

To understand better the error in the package.json please [check another StarckOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547061/npm-package-json-scripts-not-).