# Missing files in .bin folder when deploying Node App to Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, npm, github-actions

So I was trying to deploy my react app to an Azure Web App.
I used a Github Action to build and install the App and then ZIP Deploy it to Azure.
The Problem is that once I open up the WebApp Page it shows me an Application Error (react-scripts could not be found).
I found out that once I copy the react-scripts.cmd / ps1 (from local /node_modules/.bin) to the node_modules/.bin folder of the webapp "https://{WEBAPP-NAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net" it works.
Unfortunately I would have to do that after every build.
How can I come up with a solution to this error?

What I already tried:

- Update node and npm
- Remove package-lock
  Thanks in advance

Max

My package.json:

[image: Package.json]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue: [npm package.json scripts not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547061/npm-package-json-scripts-not-being-called)

Try running `npm run-script` if you want to execute a script that is not executed by a built-in `npm` command.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?
As far as I know, the App Service simply runs npm start, how / where can I cange that?

Comment: How are you calling your scripts?

Comment: Locally I simply run npm start. For the App service: I deploy it via a Github action that does a npm install, build and deploys it to the azure app service

Comment: I meant where are u calling `react-scripts`?

Comment: In the package.json under scripts (`"start" : "react-scripts start"`) (as can be seen in the screenshot above). As far as I know the `npm start` command simply runs the given code that is found under the scripts section in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

So I found out, that react-scripts is only working in dev environments. But Azure uses a production env. Therefore the github action not only has to install the prod node_modules (`npm install`) but also the dev modules (`npm install --only=dev`).

Reference:
https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/issues/32#issuecomment-276081892